# Escape 'discrete aesthetic implies group' in custom stat

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I'm trying to build a custom stat function with ggplot2 wherein I would like to access a discrete variable to compute a statistic with per group. However, the default behaviour of ggplot layers is to automatically assign implicit groups to any discrete variables (mostly). This means that my data gets split up over an automatic grouping, which I wouldn't want.

I can show this as follows; I have a pretty standard constructor:

```r
library(ggplot2)

stat_example <- function(
  mapping = NULL,
  data = NULL,
  geom = "point",
  position = "identity",
  ...,
  na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE
) {
  layer(data = data,
        mapping = mapping,
        stat = StatExample,
        geom = geom,
        position = position,
        show.legend = show.legend,
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm))
}
```

And I have a Stat ggproto object that simply passes along the data, but prints the head of the data for illustration purposes. I've called the bit that I'm interested in for computing an actual stat `value` here.

```r
StatExample <- ggproto(
  "StatExample",
  Stat,
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "value"),
  default_aes = aes(x = after_stat(x), y = after_stat(y)),
  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    print(head(data, 2))
    data
  }
)
```

Now if I construct a plot with this stat, we can see what goes into the `compute_group()` function as `data`.

```r
g <- ggplot(iris) +
  stat_example(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, value = Species))

# To get only the print side-effect, not the plot (which looks normal)
g <- ggplotGrob(g)
#>     x   y  value PANEL group
#> 1 3.5 5.1 setosa     1     1
#> 2 3.0 4.9 setosa     1     1
#>      x   y      value PANEL group
#> 51 3.2 7.0 versicolor     1     2
#> 52 3.2 6.4 versicolor     1     2
#>       x   y     value PANEL group
#> 101 3.3 6.3 virginica     1     3
#> 102 2.7 5.8 virginica     1     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I would like to have 1 data.frame containing all the data for this case. We see above that we've printed 3 data.frames with different `group` variables, meaning that the data has been split into 3 groups. What I think it would take to get there, is to have the `value` variable escape the automatic group detection.

I've considered the following points:

- I could let the group default to `-1`, which is the standard 'no group'-group. However, when I do this, the data will not get automatically grouped when for example `aes(colour = some_variable)`. This I definitively want to happen.
- Looking at `ggplot2:::add_group()` function, it seems I can escape the autogrouping by naming my `value` variable `label`, however this would make the stat incompatible with `geom_text()` and it doesn't describe the meaning of `value` naturally.
- I could replace the `layer()` call with a variant of this function, that would make a different Layer ggproto object wherein `compute_aesthetics()` works out groups differently. This however is a lot of work I would rather prevent to be burdened with.
- I could probably pull a trick along the lines of `vctrs::new_vctr(..., class = "not_discrete")`, but where is the appropriate place to wrap my `value` variable in that class?

Helpful suggestions are welcome, or new takes on 'just use `label`' arguments too.

Comment: I am actually quite curious about this. (+1) why you would need that? Isn't it the whole point about aes that it creates groups? If this is a value that should be passed to the entire data, why not passing it as a `param`, rather than as `aes`?

Comment: Well the short answer is: for this stat: https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/blob/master/R/stat_rle.R. I don't want to pass it as a param as I want the nonstandard evaluation to happen and I want it to be guaranteed parallel to the data. (but not trigger groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an occasional use case, a simple (albeit manual) hack could be running `trace(ggplot2:::add_group, edit = TRUE)` and add `"value"` alongside `"label", "PANEL"` as variable names to be excluded from automatic group detection.

A less manual (but probably more fragile) way to achieve the same effect would involve the following steps:

1. Define a modified version of the `add_group` function with the above modification;
2. Define a modified version of the `Layer` ggproto object that uses the modified `add_group` in its `compute_aesthetics` function;
3. Point the custom stat to the modified layer.

```
# define modified add_group function
add_group2 <- function (data) {
  if (ggplot2:::empty(data)) 
    return(data)
  if (is.null(data$group)) {
    disc <- vapply(data, ggplot2:::is.discrete, logical(1))
    disc[names(disc) %in% c("label", "PANEL", "value")] <- FALSE         # change here
    if (any(disc)) {
      data$group <- vctrs::vec_group_id(data[disc])
    }
    else {
      data$group <- ggplot2:::NO_GROUP
    }
  } else {
    data$group <- vctrs::vec_group_id(data["group"])
  }
  data
}

# define modified compute_aesthetics function that uses modified add_group in second last line
compute_aesthetics_alt <- .subset2(ggplot2:::Layer, "compute_aesthetics")
body(compute_aesthetics_alt)[[length(body(compute_aesthetics_alt)) - 1]] <- 
  quote(evaled <- add_group2(evaled))

# define modified Layer ggproto object that uses alternative compute_aesthetics
Layer2 <- ggproto("Layer2",
                  ggplot2:::Layer,
                  compute_aesthetics = compute_aesthetics_alt)

# define modified stat with Layer2 specified as its layer_class
stat_example <- function(
  mapping = NULL,
  data = NULL,
  geom = "point",
  position = "identity",
  ...,
  na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  inherit.aes = TRUE
) {
  layer(data = data,
        mapping = mapping,
        stat = StatExample,
        geom = geom,
        position = position,
        show.legend = show.legend,
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm),
        layer_class = Layer2) # change here
}
```

Usage:

```
# add new column to simulate different colour
iris$gg <- sample(c("a", "b"), size = nrow(iris), replace = TRUE) 

ggplot(iris) + 
  stat_example(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,
                   value = Species))
# prints one data frame, because there's only one group by default

ggplot(iris) + 
  stat_example(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,
                   value = Species, colour = gg))
# prints two data frames, because grouping is based on the colour aesthetic,
# which has two possible values
```

Comment: Thanks this works great and a lot less code that I would have expected!